# Unable to find VTK 6.1 libraries when building QT5.4 project

Tags: qt, qt5, vtk, qvtkwidget

I have installed VTK 6.1 on Ubuntu 14.04. The header files can be found at : /usr/local/include/vtk-6.1 and the libraries can be found at : /usr/local/lib.

However, when I try to include VTK into my QT5.4 project .pro file with:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/vtk-6.1
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lvtkCommon
```

It gives me the error:

```
 error: cannot find -lvtkCommon
```

I have confirmed all my library files such as libvtkCommonCore-6.1.so are in the /usr/local/lib folder. My include path is working, as I can see that QT is finding the header files.

What could the issue be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace -lvtkCommon with -lvtkCommonCore-6.1.1 or any other library that you need (they can be found in /usr/local/lib)